# Is it possible to use an if-else statement inside a JSON file?

Tags: json, if-statement

I want to include an `if-else` condition in JSON based on which I need to set an attribute in the JSON file.

For example like this:

```
"identifier": "navTag",
"items": [{
                "label": "abc",
                "url": "yxz.com",
            },
            {
                "label": "abc1",
                "url": "yxz1.com",
            },
            {
                "label": "abc2",  
                "url": "yxz2.com",/*I need to change this value on certain 
                                    condition like if condition is true then 
                                    "url": xyz2.com if false  "url":xyz3.com*/
            }
        ]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No you cannot keep this `if-else` condition in your json file. You can instead create your json using these `if-else` conditions.

Comment: You're using JSON incorrectly if you're doing this. What you *can* include is a set of keys in your JSON that you can use wisely after "JSON.parse" to evaluate conditions and decide a value. Eg "defaultUrl" : "xyz1.com", "url>0", "xyz2.com", and then evaluate if some value is > 0 and choose which key you'll use from there

Comment: This might depends ... you have tag this with `javascript`, is this a JSON content or is it the javascript ? Clean your tags based on what you want. See [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: I think yes, You can by extending **JSONObject** json class and override it's method but not sure, Didn't try before or not needed But I vote up you question for a better solution

Comment: @SamDev `I think yes, `   JSON is JSON, you can't extend it, or it wouldn't be JSON.   As a Javascript Object literal, that you get after JSON.parse, things are much more dynamic.

Comment: @Keith But this question tag with java, In java everything is possible!!

Comment: @SamDev , It doesn't matter what language, JSON is JSON.  You change the rules, it's no longer JSON.  And the question was -> `I want to include an if-else condition in json`

Comment: @Keith Everything possible what ever it Is BUT we believe when it comes front to us by implemented by someone, It's matter of time (Note: If this approach really needed for development else not)

Comment: @SamDev, `Everything possible` indeed, everything is.  But unless your a member of Network Working Group, and want to add this if-else to JSON specifications, your out of luck.  But like I said, once you have parsed JSON into your languages Object representation, the world is your Oyster, but at this point it is no longer JSON,. It's an Object.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: At the time of JSON generation you should use if else and loop. JSON is not a language it is output generated from your language.

Comment: Dear all, we don't need to waist time for un-scoped featured (putting **if-else** inside **JSON** ), When JSON come out the intelligent developers already decided best features so on. However we at-least try for something new for future. But I don't understand why **Silpa Premachandran** needed it, Still this stack overflow question not clear. Thanks

Comment: I edited the question a bit: First of all, I corrected the spelling and the formatting of the code. Second, I improved the title. There is NO `if-else loop`! It's a statement. Third, I removed all unnecessary tags. This question has nothing to do with Java or JavaScript and "ng-if-else" seems to be related to AngularJS.

Comment: Validating the [JSON Schema Draft-07](https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html), JSON now supports the `if..then...else` keywords for conditional data representation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**JSON is only** a **data** representation (unrelated to any programming language, even if early JavaScript implementations remotely inspired it). There is no notion of "execution" or "conditional" (or of "behavior" or of "[semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science))") in it.

Read carefully the (short) [JSON](http://json.org/) definition. It simply defines what sequence of characters (e.g. the content of a file) is valid JSON. It does not define the "meaning" of JSON data.

JSON data is parsed by some program, and emitted by some program (often different ones, but could be the same).

The *program* handling JSON can of course use conditions and give some "meaning" (whatever is the definition of that word) to it. But JSON is only "data syntax".

You could (easily) write your own JSON transformer (using some existing JSON library, and there are many of them), and that is really simple. Some programs (notably [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) claim to be more or less generic JSON processors.

Since JSON is a textual format, you could even use some [editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) (such as [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/), [vim](http://vim.org/) or many others) to manually change parts of it. You'll better validate the result with some existing JSON parser (to be sure you did not add any mistakes).

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a structure for storing data so that we can retrieved it much faster comparative to other data structure.So we can not give some conditions here.If you want to retrieve some data according to some if-else condition then there is two possible way,
1.We can create different JSON files for different conditions.
2.We can create two field in your JSON structure called `if` and `else`.If `if` condition satisfied then fetch the `if` field's value and if `else` satisfied then retrieved the `else` field's value.
eg:

```
{
  "if":"if-value",
  "else":"else-value"
}
```